# Função extrair coluna csv Python

Tags: python

Fiz esta função para extrair a coluna desejada do csv.
Depois, realizar um append na coluna[] passando um while para somente pegar o indice da coluna correspondente. E por fim uma condição para separar str de int.

Minha dúvida esta no retorno destes dados, que ao invés de trazer somente o tipo de dado str ele também retorna os int.
Agradeço desde já.

```
%%writefile carros.csv
id│valor_venda│valor_manutencao│portas│pessoas│porta_malas
1 │vhigh      │med             │2     │2      │small
2 │med        │vhigh           │2     │2      │small
3 │low        │vhigh           │2     │2      │small
4 │low        │high            │2     │2      │small
5 │low        │high            │2     │2      │small
6 │low        │high            │4     │4      │big
7 │low        │high            │4     │4      │big
8 │low        │med             │2     │2      │small
9 │low        │med             │2     │2      │small
10│low        │med             │2     │2      │small
11│low        │med             │4     │4      │big
12│low        │low             │2     │2      │small
13│low        │low             │4     │4      │small
14│low        │low             │4     │4      │med


def extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo: str, indice_coluna: int, tipo_dado: str):

coluna = []

    ## leia o arquivo com o comando 'with' utilizando o parametro 'nome_arquivo'
with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:

    ## extraia a coluna do arquivo utilizando o parametro 'indice_coluna'
linha = fp.readline()
linha_separada = linha.split(sep=',')
linha = linha_separada[indice_coluna]

coluna.append(linha)

    ## use a estrutura de decisão if/elif/else para fazer a conversão do tipo de dados utilizando o parametro 'tipo_dado'
while linha:

    if tipo_dado == 'str':
        coluna.append(linha)
    elif tipo_dado == 'int':
        coluna.append(linha)
    else:
        print('Error')

    linha = fp.readline()

return coluna


## extrair a coluna valor_venda
  valor_venda = extrai_coluna_csv(
  nome_arquivo='./carros.csv', indice_coluna=1, tipo_dado='str')
  print(valor_venda)  # deve retornar ['vhigh', 'med', 'low', ...]
```

Comment: sim sim, primeiro post aqui no stackoverflow, já editei. Só não consegui passar o arquivo csv. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Eu entendi o que o programa faz, mas qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Meu retorno não consegue pegar somente os valores de  # ['vhigh', 'med', 'low', ...], ele retorna todas as linhas e também os valores de int, quando somente o tipo_dado deve ser str.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não acho que este seja o jeito mais pythônico de fazer mas alterei o código com um workaround. Primeiro, tirei a declaração do tipo da variável `tipo_dado` na função `extrai_coluna_csv`. Assim, posso colocar qualquer tipo de variável ali. Comentários inline explicam o uso.

```
def extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo: str, indice_coluna: int, tipo_dado):
    print(isinstance(tipo_dado, int))
    coluna = []

    ## leia o arquivo com o comando 'with' utilizando o parametro 'nome_arquivo'
    with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:
        linha=linha = fp.readline()
        while len(linha):
            ## extraia a coluna do arquivo utilizando o parametro 'indice_coluna'
            linha = fp.readline()
            #print(linha)
            linha_separada = linha.split(sep=',')
            #print(linha_separada)
            if indice_coluna >= len(linha_separada):
                break
            
            linha = linha_separada[indice_coluna]
            coluna.append(linha)
            ## use a estrutura de decisão if/elif/else para fazer a conversão do tipo de dados utilizando o parametro 'tipo_dado'
            if isinstance(tipo_dado, str):
                coluna.append(linha)
            elif isinstance(tipo_dado, int):
                coluna.append(linha)
            else:
                print('Error')

    return coluna


## extrair a coluna valor_venda
## passei um valor do tipo string no tipo_dado
valor_venda = extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo='./carros.csv', indice_coluna=1, tipo_dado="")
print(valor_venda)  # deve retornar ['vhigh', 'med', 'low', ...]

## extrair a coluna portas
## passei um valor de tipo numérico no tipo dado
valor_venda = extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo='./carros.csv', indice_coluna=1, tipo_dado=1)
print(valor_venda)
```

Comment: Obrigado Emerson, mas já havia tentando pelo type() e mesmo assim não entrou na condição de só pegar as coluna com valores em str.

Comment: Tens razão, não funciona. Editei com um workaround que pensei aqui.

Comment: Seu código funciona bem Emerson, testei aqui e percorreu toda a lista separando por tipos. Agradeço mais uma vez pela força.

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz um pouquinho diferente, e parece que deu certo.

```
def extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo: str, indice_coluna: int, tipo_dado: str):

  coluna = []

  with open (file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
    linha = arquivo.readline()
    linha = arquivo.readline()

    while linha:
      linha_separada = linha.split(',')
      linha = linha_separada[indice_coluna]
      
      if tipo_dado in linha == 'str':
        coluna.append(linha)
      else:
        coluna.append(str(linha))
      
      linha = arquivo.readline()

  # leia o arquivo com o comando 'with' utilizando o parametro 'nome_arquivo'
  # extraia a coluna do arquivo utilizando o parametro 'indice_coluna'
  # use a estrutura de decisão if/elif/else para fazer a conversão do tipo de dados utilizando o parametro 'tipo_dado'

  return coluna
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma Resolução mais simples e seguindo as regras do exercício:

```
def extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo: str, indice_coluna: int, tipo_dado: str):

  coluna = []

  with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
    linha = arquivo.readline()
    linha = arquivo.readline()

    while linha:
        linha_separada = linha.split(sep=',')

        if tipo_dado == 'str':
            valorSeparado = valorSeparado = str(linha_separada[indice_coluna])
        elif tipo_dado == 'int':
          valorSeparado = valorSeparado = int(linha_separada[indice_coluna])
        else:
          print('<<<ERROR>>>')
        coluna.append(valorSeparado)
        linha = arquivo.readline()
  

    
    return coluna
```

Se quiser deixar mais completa, faça o tratamento de erro!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Consegui resolver o exercício completo da seguinte forma:

```py
def extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo: str, indice_coluna: int, tipo_dado: str):

    coluna = []

    ## leia o arquivo com o comando 'with' utilizando o parametro 'nome_arquivo'
    with open(file=nome_arquivo, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:

        linha=fp.readline()
        linha=fp.readline()
        ## extraia a coluna do arquivo utilizando o parametro 'indice_coluna'
        while linha:
            indice_coluna=linha.split(sep=',')
            ## use a estrutura de decisão if/elif/else para fazer a conversão do tipo de dados utilizando o parametro 'tipo_dado'
            if tipo_dado == 'str':
                valor_v=indice_coluna[1]
                coluna.append(valor_v)
            elif tipo_dado == 'int':
                v_pessoas=indice_coluna[4]
                coluna.append(v_pessoas)
        linha=fp.readline() 
return coluna
```